# Scheduling an Event with MassTransit.AmazonSQS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit

I am using [masstransit](https://masstransit-project.com/)  for distributed messaging in my software, what I am trying to achieve for this particular use-case is to create a scheduled message that would be trigger after a particular time

```
await  _publishEndpoint.SchedulePublish<ScheduleNotification>( 
        DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180),
        new
    {
         DeliveryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1.5),
         scheduleNotification.Body,
         scheduleNotification.EmailAddress
    });
```

https://github.com/makafanpeter/Demo.ScheduleMessages/blob/6f92955d8697acaefdac74426210d7411cd69a82/ScheduleMessages/Controllers/NotificationController.cs#L30

But what I have noticed here is that this message is beening trigger immediately it has been published instead of waiting till the scheduled time.

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ScheduleNotification> context)
{
    await context.ScheduleSend<SendNotification>(
        context.Message.DeliveryTime,
        new 
        {
            EmailAddress = context.Message.EmailAddress,
            Body =  context.Message.Body
        });
}
```

Setting up MassTransit with the In-Memory transport worked for scheduling messages; The published events are not executed till the delay has elapsed.

```
 services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
                x.AddConsumer(typeof(ScheduleNotificationConsumer));
                x.AddConsumer(typeof(SendNotificationConsumer));
                x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
                {



                    cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
```

Trying to Do the same with AmazonSQS Transport Does not work as expected because the scheduled messages are executed immediately after the events are published.

```
  services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {

                x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
                // add all consumers in the specified assembly
                x.AddConsumer(typeof(ScheduleNotificationConsumer));
                x.AddConsumer(typeof(SendNotificationConsumer));

                x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
                {

                    cfg.Host(region, h =>
                    {
                        h.AccessKey(ACCESS_KEY_ID);
                        h.SecretKey(SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
                        // scope topics as well
                        h.EnableScopedTopics();

                    });
                    cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

                });

            });
```

What could I have been doing wrong?
I have the source code available at https://github.com/makafanpeter/Demo.ScheduleMessages

Comment: In that consumer, you should be specifying an endpoint address as the first parameter, which would be the destination address for the scheduled message.

Comment: Hello @ChrisPatterson, Thank you for your feedback, But Unfortunately, I can't get my source code to work as expected, I would appreciate it if you can share a sample with me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the [unit tests](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/tests/MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.Tests).

Comment: Ok, Thanks @ChrisPatterson !

Comment: Hello @ChrisPatterson,  Using the In-Memory Transport I was able to schedule events for a later time, doing the same with the AmazonSQS does not work as expected, the events are executed immediately, I have updated my question to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: SNS doesn't have a delay capability, so delayed publishing won't work with SNS. You'd have to send directly to the queue for the delay to be used.